# What happens to active child processes when you fork a parent, do all active processes create another process ? Fork();

Tags: c, printing, process, fork, child-process

Bellow is the code of what is going on , and here is an image of what am i trying to do , any help would be appreciated.[Trying to draw the diagram of all the processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuZGn.png)
Code:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        fork();
    printf("\tA\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\tB\n");
    }
}//for
printf("\tC\n");
return 0;
```

}

[This is the code of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHeXL.png)

[This is the output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJax7.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the image _of what am i trying to do_ is a _screen shot_?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly missing from your diagram is in the block *Child1* as well as *Child1.1* a second run through the `for` loop, since these children are still inside the loop and their `i` is initially also 0.
On the other hand, the *C=3* in *Parent* is wrong because *C* is only printed once at the end, not in the loop.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful , it's an image not a screen shot my bad firstly i created a diagram online i took a screenshot but it was not clear. Thanks again have a good day!